# Pusher - autenticated users not receiving events from private channels

Tags: python, django, pusher, pusher-js

Let's say I have a vue client trying to receive an event from a private channel using `pusher` services.

This client autenticates using pusher auth secuence:
[image]

Here are the docs: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/

Seems I need to provide an endpoint on my server in order to autenticate the user.

So, as the docs [says](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/#using-jsonp-in-pusher-js), since my server is in a different domain to the front-end app, I need to use `CORS` or `JSONP`, I choose JSONP.

My server (backend) is made in `Django` using `django-rest-framework` and it provides an endpoint that is responsible to process the `socket_id`, the `channel_name` and the `callback` that the `pusher-js` (which is a pusher frontend library) generates.

Something alike to a javascript code is sent to the frontend, so the response needs to be `content-type:application/javascript`.

In order to test the event, I made a simple python script which I will later integrate to my bussiness logic. This script is the responsible to trigger the event.

**The problem**: The main problem is the event never arrives. I looked up into the web-console (frontend) to check the correct function of the requests. The `ws protocol` requests responds with `status 101` and the endpoint `/auth/pusher` with `status 200`. So they seem to work correctly.

- Here is my Django `/auth/pusher` endpoint:

> ```
> def get(self, request):
>   pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
>       app_id = settings.P_APP_ID,
>       key = settings.P_APP_KEY,
>       secret = settings.P_APP_KEY_SECRET,
>       cluster = settings.P_REGION_CLUSTER,
>       ssl = True
>   )
>
>   auth = pusher_client.authenticate(
>       channel=request.query_params.get('channel_name'),
>       socket_id=request.query_params.get('socket_id')
>   )
>
>   callback_query_params = request.query_params.get('callback')
>
>   callback = re.sub(r'/\\"/g', '', callback_query_params) + "(" + str(auth) + ");";
>
>   return Response(callback, content_type = 'application/javascript')
> ```

- Here is the important part of the pusher connection in vue:

> ```
> var pusher = new Pusher(env.pusher_app_key, {
>       cluster: 'us2',
>       authTransport: "jsonp",
>       authEndpoint: "http://localhost:8000/pusher/auth",
>     });
>
> var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-cesar');
>
> channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
>   console.log(data);
>   this.messages.push(JSON.stringify(data));
> });
> ```

- Here is the python script I made to trigger the event manually:

> ```
> import pusher
>
> pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
>       app_id = settings.P_APP_ID,
>       key = settings.P_APP_KEY,
>       secret = settings.P_APP_KEY_SECRET,
>       cluster = settings.P_REGION_CLUSTER,
>       ssl = True
>   )
>
>   while True: 
>       option = input("Send? (Y/N)") 
>       if option.lower() == "y":
>           pusher_client.trigger('private-cesar', 'my-event', {'message': 'test from python'}) 
>           print("Sent")
>       else:
>           break
> ```

So, what seems to be the problem here, is there something I'm missing?

I already figured out how to use it without auth, And it works as expected, but in that case I don't need to have a `auth/pusher` endpoint.

Comment: I know I am coming a bit late, but are you sure the endpoint you need to implement is a GET endpoint? From the [documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/), all of the examples implement a POST endpoint. Have you solved this in the meantime?

Comment: Hello, don't worry, any help is welcome at any time. I did not solved this yet, I paused the implementation of that module meanwhile I think on a better solution or a figure out what's the problem with the auth.

Yes, you are right, most of the examples implements a POST endpoint. But,  since my server is in a different domain to the web app, I need to use JSONP.

 When I set-up the JSONP params on the pusher client instantiation, pusher-js automatically requests for a GET endpoint, not a POST endpoint. 

At the docs, where they explain the JSONP method, they example a GET endpoint

Comment: Did you try to serialize `auth` into JSON first? the docs show that when returning the JSONP, the `auth` variable is [first serialized into JSON](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/#using-jsonp-in-pusher-js), just like the auth endpoint was doing in python with `return json.dumps(auth)` in [this snippet](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/#implementing-the-auth-endpoint-for-a-presence-channel).

Comment: No, I solved yet. The problem was the response type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Finally, I solved this. Turns out I needed to return an `HttpResponse` object, which is provided by `django.http`, not the `Response` that `rest_framework.response` provides.

My mistake: believing that `rest_framework.response` is implicit an http response.

imports:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

So the endpoint ended like this:

```
def get(self, request):
        pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
            app_id = settings.P_APP_ID,
            key = settings.P_APP_KEY,
            secret = settings.P_APP_KEY_SECRET,
            cluster = settings.P_REGION_CLUSTER,
            ssl = True
        )

        auth = pusher_client.authenticate(
            channel=request.query_params.get('channel_name'),
            socket_id=request.query_params.get('socket_id')
        )

        callback_query_params = request.query_params.get('callback')

        callback = re.sub(r'/\\"/g', '', callback_query_params) + "(" + str(auth) + ");";

        return HttpResponse(callback, content_type = 'application/javascript')
```